# Fine-tune VGG or AlexNet for non-square inputs

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe, vgg-net

VGG and AlexNet, amongst others, require a fixed image input of square dimensions (`H` == `W`). How can one fine-tune or otherwise perform net surgery such that non-square inputs can be provided?

For your reference, I'm using Caffe and intend to extract `FC7` features for non-square image inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For the convolutional part of the net - the input size does not really matter: the shape of the output will change as you change the input size.
However, when it comes to `"InnerProduct"` layers - the shape of the weights is fixed and it is determined by input size.

You can perform ["net surgery"](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb#Casting-a-Classifier-into-a-Fully-Convolutional-Network) converting your `"InnerProduct"` layers into `"Convolution"` layers: This way your net can process inputs at any size they come. However, your outputs will also vary in shape.

Another option is to define your net according to a new **fixed** input size, re-use all the learned weights of the covolutions and only fine-tune the weights of the fully connected layers.

Comment: If I convert the InnerProduct layers to Convolution layers, how to extract a 1D feature vecture? (note: my goal is to extract features for image search)